# SSH Tunnel with key on first server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Im trying to tunnel to `DestinationHost` through `HopHost` with

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh HopHostUser@HopHost nc -w 10 %h %p' DestinationHost
```

First, I get to authenticate towards HopHost as HopHostUser

```
HopHostUser@HopHost password:
```

After I authenticate towards HopHost, I get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

`HopHostUser`'s connection to `DestinationHost` is authenticated with a key, which are on configed for `HopHostUser` on `HopHost`

If I were to connect towards DestinationHost through HopHost step by step, (without it being a tunnel / proxy) All i would have to is this:

```
 me@localhost >> ssh HopHostUser@HopHost
 HopHostUser@HopHost password:
 HopHostUser@HopHost >> ssh DestinationHost
 HopHostUser@DestionationHost >>
```

If i use `-v` to the original ssh command, I can see that the key on my localhost, instead of on HopHost

Can i tell SSH to use the external Key, instead of looking on my localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* use proxying/tunneling as the ssh-key is stored on the hop server and isn't accessible locally. Ideally you generate a new key and add it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `DestinationHost`, but this may not be possible.

The easiest way to set this up is using the remote command and two local port forwards.

Open terminal on *DestinationHost*:

`ssh -t HopHostUser@HopHost "ssh DestinationHost"`

Open terminal + port forwarding from *DestinationHost* to *Localhost*:

`ssh -t -L8081:localhost:9999 HopHostUser@HopHost "ssh -L9999:localhost:80 DestinationHost"`

You best make use of you ssh config for this. It's very long winded.

Comment: Its correct that i cannot do this without a new key, And i cannot add a new key. A port forwading option would work, but i need to use scp. I solved it by it by using non orthodox methods (copy key)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
ssh HopHostUser@HopHost ssh DestinationHost
```

I used to do this a few years ago, maybe ssh prevents this now. I haven't access to several hosts so I'm unable to test this command.

Comment: This works, but it doesnt make it a tunnel as for as I can tell.